# Using LIKE statement in SQLite 3 from Objective-C

Tags: ios, select, sqlite

I am running with one `LIKE` statement problem.
The situation is that:

1. I'm saving phone number and name associated with that number from the contact book to app's db.
2. Then I am displaying this name in the uitableview by firing this query ...

   ```
   NSString  *sqlTemp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name from phoneData where number like %'%@'%",number1];
   ```

   `number1` is `(NSString *)`, the number I'm using is formatted like this `(+international country code number)`. However number saved in db might be without country code and not prefixed with "`+`" symbol.

So my question is that even if number saved in the contacts book is not according to the international phone number, how can I ensure that it matches the other digits in the number?

Can any one suggest me some solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange (3, [number1 length] - 3);
NSString *noPrefixNumber = [number1 substringWithRange:range];
NSString  *sqlTemp =[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"select name from phoneData where number like %'%@'%",noPrefixNumber ];
```

Comment: Your answer includes code that isn't syntactically valid. It looks like a line got omitted altogether. Please edit your answer to fix this.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply but this displays only such names which are not according to the international code.